# Eclipse can't handle CSS3 Animations

Tags: eclipse, css, formatting, newline

I was wondering if anybody could tell me why eclipse seems determined to not format the code for css3 animations correctly, more specifically it inserts newlines into the keyframe rules. ANy tips on how to fix this?

Comment: I know it's not the right answer, but Eclipse seems a horrible tool for web design to me - big, slow, bloated etc. You might find a tool like Sublime Text to make things easier + the fact you can easily find a myriad of plugins to help with things like this. Of course, you likely know all that, so just ignore if so!

Comment: To help us to help you, could you specify what Eclipse and WTP versions are you using?

Comment: I am using eclipse 4.x with the latest WTP. And I know it's bad for web design, but I have a outdated version of dreamweaver. Bleah cs4 :-@

Comment: netbeans is free and absolutely great, give it a try ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accordingly to [this comment](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=324731#c8)

> Also, CSS3 is not the default CSS-level. So when the time comes you'll
>   need to modify the Web Content Settings at either the project level or
>   file level by right clicking on the project or file and selecting
>   Properties. Select Web Content Settings and change CSS Profile to
>   "Cascading Style Sheets, level 3".

Verify if your version of the WTP is, at least, 3.2.3.

Try it. If you still go into formatting problems I suggest you to add an issue at Eclipse Bug track.

You can also try installing [Aptana Studio 3](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download) Eclipse plugin version.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it when I get back to my Eclipse Setup